# D operators method

Tags: differential-operators

Find P.I. of the following equation:
$$(D^2-1)y=(1+x^2)e^x$$
I have tried like this:
$$\begin{align}
P.I.& =\frac{(1+x^2)e^x}{D^2-1}\\
& =e^x\frac{(1+x^2)}{(D+1)^2-1}\\
& =e^x\frac{(1+x^2)}{D^2+2D}\\
& =e^x\frac{1}{D+2}\frac{1}{D}(1+x^2)\\
& =e^x\frac{1}{D+2}\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3}\right)\\
& =e^x\frac{1}{D+2}x+\frac{e^x}{3}\frac{1}{D+2}x^3\\
& =.....................\\
& =\frac{1}{2}xe^x+\frac{1}{6}x^3e^x-\frac{3}{8}e^x\\
\end{align}$$
But in my book the answer is:
$$\frac{1}{12}xe^x(2x^2-3x+9)$$
Please check where is my fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start with OP's work from the step:
$$y=e^x\frac{1}{D+2} x+ \frac{e^x}{3}\frac{1}{D+2}x^3$$
$$\implies y=\frac{e^x}{2}(1+D/2)^{-1} x+\frac{e^x}{6}(1+D/2)^{-1}$$
$$\implies y=\frac{e^x}{2}(1-D/2+D^2/4+..)x+\frac{e^x}{6}(1-D/2+D^2/4-D^3/8)x^3$$
$$\implies y=e^x[x^3/6-x^2/4+3x/4-3/8]~~~(1)$$

Hence OP's and book's answers are not correct.  The simple indicator in OP's answer
is the absence of $x^2$. Absence of constant term in book's answer indicates error.
Using $y$ from (1) one can check that $$(D^2-1)y=(1+x^2)e^x$$